# findByIdAndUpdate and push in mongodb issue ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am new to Mongodb and I am using findByIdAndUpdate  which will update document but returning the old document , 
Here is my function  ,

```
exports.createInner = function (req, res, next) {

    console.log("req", req.body);
    var innerFolderDetails = req.body.innerFolder;
    Repository.findByIdAndUpdate(innerFolderDetails._id, {
        $push: {
            innerFolder: {
                "foldername": innerFolderDetails.foldername,
                "ismainFolder": innerFolderDetails.ismainFolder,
                "parentfolderId": innerFolderDetails.parentfolderId,
            }

        }
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log(response);
        res.json(response);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findByIdAndUpdate` can accept an options object as a third argument.

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateObject, {
    new: true // get the modified document back
}, callback);
```

By default the value of `new` options is `false`